# How to set color for 1 item on grid layout by index QML?

Tags: qt, colors, grid, qml

I cannot set color for item on grid layout by index on QML.
I have a grid of rectangle

```
Grid {
    visible: true
    id: grid
    columns: matrixSize
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    Repeater{
        model: 256
        //model: serial.modelData
        Rectangle{
            id: cell
            width: square_size
            height: square_size
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 1
            Text {
                id: txt
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                // text: model.modelData
                text: index
                color: "black"
            }
            color:{
                for(temp = 4; temp <14; temp++){
                    cell.color[temp] = "yellow"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is not work. The color is not change.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you want to do here? `Rectangle.color` is a property of type `color`, you can get or set it, not to add some strange logic to that. if you want to access Repeater's item you can use [Repeater.itemAt()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#itemAt-method)

Comment: I want to set color for some rectangle (rectangle 4 to rectangle 14 in repeater)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Reapeater.itemAt(temp) = "yellow"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change line 22 of your code as follows:

```
        color: (index >= 4 && index <= 14) ? "yellow" : "white";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use **Positioner.index** to find out the index of an item inside **Repeater**. Check the docs